# Nothing shows in "My Documents" even when I create directory using mkdir

Tags: windows, git, bash, mkdir

I am using git bash and I want to create a directory in My Documents.

While in My Documents folder I do the following:

```
mkdir Dummy_directory
```

Next I  type `ls` , but the directory doesn't show up.  I also tried `ls -a` in  case the directory was hidden for some reason.  still doesn't show up.  Any ideas why?  thanks <3

Comment: However, the  `Dummy_directory` does show up under Documents - just not My Documents.    I should  mention that, in general, on Windows 7 I have found differences between Documents, and My Documents, which is confusing because people have told me that they are the same?

Comment: Note to reviewer: this is 100% on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use [`git-cmd`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) and a plain DOS session, in order to go to the right `My Documents` folder and type:

```
git init Dummy_directory
(or just mkdir, if you don't want to create a git repo there)
```

Considering "[`My Documents`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Documents)" is a [special folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) on W7+, it can act for a git bash session as a kind of symbolic link to the `Documents` folder:

> As of Windows 7, the "`Documents`", "`Pictures`", "`Music`" and "`Videos`" folders appear displayed in Windows Explorer with a "`My`" prefix but are actually still stored in the file system without the prefix.

Comment: I do not know what is a "plain DOS session".  `git-cmd` is not recognized as a command.

Comment: A cmd session, if you will. Type cmd in the windows Execute box. And use the full path of your git installation before the git-cmd.bat script.